# How to build a java project with all the required files and folders?

Tags: java, netbeans, build-automation

I created a simple application which will read all the files and folders kepts inside a folder. Whenever I build the project, I only get the jar file but the folder where the file and folders are kept have to be created. Is this supposed to be like this or I have to code something, which will create the folder upon the final build.

Comment: More details please. What are you using to compile the project? Eclipse? Ant?

Comment: @Grook, @Robin Green I am sorry the confusion, I meant build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compilation gives you only executable file (i.e. *.jar). If you need something else to make you application works - you must do it (programmatically or not).

Comment: Yes but other files can be created at build time. mrN seems to be unaware of the distinction between build and compilation. (build can encompass more activities.)

Comment: Oh, I see. So i think you may found interesting Maven and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085973/create-directory-when-needed-in-maven)