# Creating directory structure for application with maven

Tags: maven, build

How can I tell maven to create a particular directory structure and to put jar files in certain places?

For example I want to put put some jars in a directory called `plugins` which are loaded at runtime.

Is that possible? Or am I missing the principles behind maven?

Comment: possible duplicate of [create directory when needed in maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085973/create-directory-when-needed-in-maven)

Comment: @ericbn That question is only about how to create a new directory but how can I then put the compiled JAR in that directory?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your jars is your project dependency, so to copy all dependencies at **plugins** folder use next:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-alldeps</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/plugins</outputDirectory>
          <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
          <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
          <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
          <excludeTransitive>false</excludeTransitive>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

When your project use jars like resources, use maven **resource** section or next plugin:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>copy-config-files</id>
               <phase>package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>copy-resources</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                   <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/plugins/</outputDirectory>

                   <resources>
                       <resource>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/jars/</directory>
                        <includes>
                          <include>file1.jar</include>
                          <include>file5.jar</include>
                        </includes>
                       </resource>

                   </resources>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
       </executions>
    </plugin>
```