# How to create folder automatically with Jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins so I have the following question.

I need a Jenkins job, which can create a folder in my project automatically, say **/project-core/configuration/scripts/newfolder**. Furthermore, the new job should create a **new file** in the newly created folder and add some text into that file.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can just run a shell/Batch depends on the environment you run on (Linux/Windows)

this script can work on both windows and Linux:

```
mkdir /project-core/configuration/scripts/newfolder
echo New_File_Content>/project-core/configuration/scripts/newfolder/New_File.txt
```

[image]

Comment: I get the error: + mkdir  /project-core/configuration/scripts/newfolder
mkdir: cannot create directory ` /project-core/configuration/scripts/newfolder': No such file or directory

Comment: are you using Linux?

Comment: Than you can use this command: mkdir /project-core/configuration/scripts/newfolder -p

Comment: @Ronald Did it help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111509/discussion-between-ronald-and-shachar-hamuzim-rajuan).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's certainly possible. You really have your choice of how you want to create the directory / file. I don't use maven personally, but it's looks like [there are ways to create directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085973/create-directory-when-needed-in-maven) directly from maven. Or you can run groovy code, shell script, custom code, etc to accomplish this.